# How to use variable for file descriptor with flock?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, file-descriptor, flock

I would like to do like this

```
( flock --nonblock ${descr} || exit

... 

) ${descr}>/tmp/smth.lock
```

but I got errors:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `${descr}'
`) ${descr}>/tmp/smth.lock'
```

So is it possible to use variable for descriptor? Could anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `{descr}>/tmp/smth.lock` (no dollar sign) to allocate the file descriptor and assign it to the variable `descr`. After this, you could use `descr` as a normal variable.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on Mac OS X? Having a frustratingly hard time getting this to work.

Comment: What is this magic? What are documentations related to this?

Comment: It was added (I think) to `bash` 4.1, documented in the second paragraph of the `REDIRECTION` section of the man page.